# How to split SQL table into multiple worksheets in excel

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I have few large tables in SQL server.
I am trying to get the data in excel but excel has limitation in terms of number of rows. Also if no of rows are more, excel response is very sluggish.
Due to this I am trying to get my data split in multiple worksheets say 300,000 rows in each sheet with help of VBA in Excel.
For eg if query result is having 800,000 rows, VBA will import 1st 300,000 rows in Sheet name A1, next 300,000 rows in sheet name A2 and balance 200,000 in sheet name A3.

I am able to import entire query result in one go from sql but unable to work on basis of no of rows.

Pl help.
Thanks//Ketan

Comment: The [CopyFromRecordset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/vba/api/excel.range.copyfromrecordset) method on a Range object takes a `MaxRows` parameter that would do what you need. To use this would require you to be using VBA and ADODB or something similar to import the data in the first place. Can you show or describe how you are importing the data at the moment?

Comment: Use  rs.getrows.  It get data as 2d array. But row and  column is transposed.  You can resize  another 2d array base on  original array.